# I am getting this errror in my code "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1" ,how will i solve this?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
    int i;
    boolean flag = false;
    String str;
    String sub;
    String strf;
    try
    {

        str = jTextField1.getText();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\dictionary.txt");
        BufferedReader bb = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while((strf = bb.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.out.println(strf);
            i = strf.indexOf("  ");
            sub = strf.substring(0,i);
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(sub))
            {
                jTextArea2.setText(strf.substring(i+1,strf.length()));                  
                flag=true;
                break;
            }

        }
        bb.close();

        if(!flag)
            System.out.println("Word not found");

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

while searching meaning of a word in dictionary text file I am getting "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1" exception after searching for certain words from the beginning.

Comment: `i = strf.indexOf("  ");` you should make sure that the value of `i` isn't -1, i.e. there's no space character in the line read.

Comment: `-1` is a normal return value for `String#indexOf(String)` that indicates that the string you were trying to find didn't exist in the target string. You're currently assuming that whatever you search for **will** be present because you're not checking for the potential that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

You get an index -1 if [indexof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) do not find the specified string in your string (strf):

```
        //System.out.println(strf);
        i = strf.indexOf("  "); // returns -1
        sub = strf.substring(0,i);
```

So before you call substring you have to check if the i is greater -1

```
        //System.out.println(strf);
        i = strf.indexOf("  ");
        if (i>-1) {
         sub = strf.substring(0,i);
         .....
        }
```

Comment: @AkankshaKumari So it is helped, feel free to accept and/or upvote myanswer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line :

```
 i = strf.indexOf("  ");
```

if there are no 2 consecutive spaces in your string, i will be `-1` and then you are calling `strf.substring(0,i);` which will give the error. Print the string and check whether the `"  "` is present.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `strf.indexOf("  ")` is greater than -1. Take a look at String documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

If you can't find the string you'll get -1.

Modify your code to

```
if (i != -1){ 
  sub = strf.substring(0,i);
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(sub))
        {
            jTextArea2.setText(strf.substring(i+1,strf.length()));                  
            flag=true;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) of indexOf states that

> ```
> public int indexOf(String str)
> ```
>
> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified substring.
>
> The returned index is the smallest value k for which:
>
> ```
>  this.startsWith(str, k)
> ```
>
> **If no such value of k exists, then -1 is returned.**

So you need to handle `-1` value in your code.

```
i = strf.indexOf("  ");
if (i > -1) {
    //code here
}
```